# How to set the SQL dialect in node-sql?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, dialect

I am trying to include the [node-sql](https://npmjs.org/package/sql) module in a `node.js` project. It generates SQL statements from Javascript for mysql, postgresql and sqllite.

I have searched the documentation, but I does not explain how to set the dialect to generate SQL statements. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql.setDialect('pg'); // Sets dialect for Postgres.
```

https://github.com/brianc/node-sql/blob/master/test/index-tests.js